# Oracle Apex Text Area store data into table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a text area field in my page and a submit button which should insert the values inside a table with a process after submit (processing->After submit->Process):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name)
(SELECT RTRIM(COLUMN_VALUE, CHR(13)) 
            FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(:my_text_area, CHR(10))));
```

This works very well but not for > 2000 rows. Is there a limitation for submitting more then X character? The large data is correctly inserted into the text area field, I checked.

Is there any alternative way to paste data into a region and insert it into an existing table (without file upload)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a character limit on the text area. You'll have to google what it is (either 4k or 32k not sure). In the upcoming version 22.2 there will be CLOB support for page items so then this should be possible.

In the versions below 22.2 you can use a plugin (for example this one: https://github.com/OraOpenSource/apex-plugin-clob-load). But then you cannot use a page process to loop through the strings since the plugin will save the value in a table. You'll probably have to  implement the logic you have in the question in a trigger or a procedure on the table where the clob is saved to.